# Animation of embedded SVG into CSS background

Tags: css, svg, background, hover, uri

I have the goal of hover-animate something like a stylish swirl (like that [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWFZF.png)) in an existing html page. In other words, I would like to apply a path drawing animation in a custom swirl, when "hovering" some element.
But I have some restrictions:

1. I just can edit the .css file (the site only permits .css file submissions for user customization). So, I can't create more html elements. I have just the existent ones to work with. Therefore, I can't insert svg at the html.
2. There are no svg elements available on the html.

After some days working on ideas and doing some research, I've concluded that injecting svg into a css background via data URI encoding would be the way to accomplish my goal. I was able to achieve the follow results:

1. Handle the static svg like a css background via something like this:

`background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,[svg URI encoded]");`

2. Handle the animated svg in a similar way descripted above, but without interactive control, without my so expected hover-effect. The animation just starts with the rendering of the background.
3. Placing the entire item2 inside an element hover, I get a result near to my objective, but with a practical problem: The hover state doesn't starts the animation, but resumes it. Every time a hover occurs, the animation continues from where it has stopped. Here is the code which represents this specific problem:

```css
.sample {
    margin: 0;
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.sample:hover{
   background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 90 30' width='90' height='30'%3E%3Cstyle%3Ecircle{fill:%234c4d4e}%3C/style%3E%3Ccircle cx='15' cy='15' r='0'%3E%3Canimate attributeName='r' attributeType='XML' from='0' to='0' begin='0' dur='1.4s' values='0;10;0;0' keyTimes='0;0.2;0.7;1' calcMode='spline' keySplines='0.42 0 0.58 1;0.42 0 0.58 1;0 0 1 1' repeatCount='indefinite'/%3E%3C/circle%3E%3Ccircle cx='45' cy='15' r='0'%3E%3Canimate attributeName='r' attributeType='XML' from='0' to='0' begin='0.3s' dur='1.4s' values='0;10;0;0' keyTimes='0;0.2;0.7;1' calcMode='spline' keySplines='0.42 0 0.58 1;0.42 0 0.58 1;0 0 1 1' repeatCount='indefinite'/%3E%3C/circle%3E%3Ccircle cx='75' cy='15' r='0'%3E%3Canimate attributeName='r' attributeType='XML' from='0' to='0' begin='0.6s' dur='1.4s' values='0;10;0;0' keyTimes='0;0.2;0.7;1' calcMode='spline' keySplines='0.42 0 0.58 1;0.42 0 0.58 1;0 0 1 1' repeatCount='indefinite'/%3E%3C/circle%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
 <div class="sample">
  </div>
```

The svg applied in this code is just a random example. Anyway, assuming that is not possible control the animation inside the svg (I unsuccessfully tried to do it via SMIL with attributes like 'begin=click or begin=mouseover' and via CSS injected into the svg in a  tag, something like [id-of-svg-path]:hover), I started to try figure out about how to restart the rendering of the svg. With this, every time the element is hovered the svg would be restarted and the animation would start again from the real begin. 
As you can see, the only thing I need in this case is some workaround that restarts the svg on hover. Maybe some attribute in SMIL should works? Or a trick in the css?
I would appreciate to receive some help on this :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a tricky way with javascript, everytime mouse is over, the svg will be added with one randomized attribute.

Like this: random='${Math.random()}'

It will be better if each time this randomized string is generated by utilizing a uuid generator.

```js
$('.sample').mouseover(function() {
  var data = `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' random='${Math.random()}' viewBox='0 0 90 30' width='90' height='30'%3E%3Cstyle%3Ecircle{fill:%234c4d4e}%3C/style%3E%3Ccircle cx='15' cy='15' r='0'%3E%3Canimate attributeName='r' attributeType='XML' from='0' to='0' begin='0;sample.click' dur='1.4s' values='0;10;0;0' keyTimes='0;0.2;0.7;1' calcMode='spline' keySplines='0.42 0 0.58 1;0.42 0 0.58 1;0 0 1 1' repeatCount='indefinite'/%3E%3C/circle%3E%3Ccircle cx='45' cy='15' r='0'%3E%3Canimate attributeName='r' attributeType='XML' from='0' to='0' begin='0.3s;sample.mouseover' fill='remove' dur='1.4s' values='0;10;0;0' keyTimes='0;0.2;0.7;1' calcMode='spline' keySplines='0.42 0 0.58 1;0.42 0 0.58 1;0 0 1 1' repeatCount='indefinite'/%3E%3C/circle%3E%3Ccircle cx='75' cy='15' r='0'%3E%3Canimate attributeName='r' attributeType='XML' from='0' to='0' begin='0.6s;sample.mouseover' fill='remove' dur='1.4s' values='0;10;0;0' keyTimes='0;0.2;0.7;1' calcMode='spline' keySplines='0.42 0 0.58 1;0.42 0 0.58 1;0 0 1 1' repeatCount='indefinite'/%3E%3C/circle%3E%3C/svg%3E`;
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url("' + data + '")');
});
$('.sample').mouseout(function() {
  $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
});
```

```css
.sample {
    margin: 0;
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sample" id="sample"></div>
```

Comment: What a trick! Your result is exactly what I need, the animation correctly restarts everytime the element is hovered. But for achieve this I would need access to the html and put the js script in there, right? I do not have this access. I can only submit a .css file for this site. So, do you know any way to embedded this js into the .css file?

Comment: In this case, you'll need to find a way to embed javascript into css file, I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: I found tools like this https://github.com/campbeln/CjsSS.js, but it still needs you to add other javascript files. Maybe you'd better ask for more access.